# Problems getting python to start threads at a given time

Tags: python

I am writing a small app that is meant to awake at 09:00 every day and fetch data from some sources. However when I review my logs and database entries I am seeing that this executes at 09:00 and again at 10:00.

The scraping process at most takes 15 minutes to complete, this has me totally stumped.

```
while 1:

    if time.strftime("%H") == "09" and time.strftime("%M") == "00":
        print "Starting at: " + time.strftime("%H") + ":" + time.strftime("%M")
        worker1.startThread()
        worker2.startThread()

    time.sleep(30)
```

In my logs i am essentially seeing

```
Starting at: 09:00
     <snip>
Starting at: 10:00
```

Comment: Scheduling things are usually best done with the operating systems scheduler, ie crontab. That said, have you at any time had the value "10" when you ran this? Because it looks like an old process that is set to start at 10 is still running.

Comment: Controlling it inside the script like this was just convenient for me a the moment. I have checked my running processes and no sign of older instances - good suggestion tho.

Comment: If you are on windows, then maybe it's convenient, I don't know. But I imagine that if there is no good scheduler for Windows, then installing it would be quite trivial. So of you think it was convenient for you then you are unfortunately mistaken. Using crontab is much quicker and more convenient than trying to do scheduling yourself.

Comment: Is there a reason you're making all these separate calls to `strftime`? Or, for that matter, a reason why you're using string comparisons on something that would be much more natural to do with actual numbers? My guess is that the scenario @Kos mentioned is happening more often than you expect, and it could be easily remedied by restructuring your code a little: `t = time.localtime()` `if t[3:5] == (9, 0): # Do stuff` Also, you could do something nicer at the end of your loop, like calculate how many seconds you need to sleep until the next run, which could negate the check altogether.

Comment: It's quite hand-wavy so far. Any chance you can give more information? For example, I can't find `startThread` in the Python documentation, and if you're rolling you're own, who knows what's in there? Your `print` statement has no chance of producing the stated output (yes, yes, you said "essentially", but why insert `'scraper'` into the output; how does that help illuminate your situation?). I guess what I'm saying is, to the extent that you can manage, don't give us pseudocode and hand-crafted output, give us *actual* code and *actual* output.

Comment: @JohnY I have updated the log output to reflect the code. The startThread method calls "thread.start_new_thread(getStats,())" in the referenced classes. Apart from the slightly different comment the sample code represents my code almost exactly.

Comment: @HenryKeiter No reason at all, given your comments and the comments above I will just make a single call to get the current time and do a numeric compare after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for clarity I'm going to wrap up some of the suggestions in this answer. First, my guess is that the problem is actually the one that Kos describes, and I'm thinking it happens more often than you expect it does. Making two calls to `time.strftime` (actually four, but two of them are just for printing) means you're making two (four) calls under the hood to `time.localtime`, and since you're checking every thirty seconds, there's a good chance that if you finish very near an exact minute, you'll end up with values straddling the 10:00 hour reasonably often. This is how I'd fix it:

```
while True:
    t = time.localtime()
    if t[3:5] == (9, 0): # Compare (hour, day) numerically
        print time.strftime("Starting at: %H:%M", t)
        worker1.startThread()
        worker2.startThread()
        time.sleep(get_nap_length())
    else:
        time.sleep(59) # No need to sleep less than this, even being paranoid.

def get_nap_length():
    '''Returns approximate number of seconds before 9:00am tomorrow.

    Probably implementing this would be easiest with the datetime module.'''
```

I'll leave the implementation of `get_nap_length` to you if you feel like it. I'd have it return something like the number of seconds until tomorrow at 8:58 am, just for safety. Implementing this would cut down on the number of "useless" times you go through the loop, and therefore reduce your chances of misfiring somehow. Note that if you *don't* implement this, you also need to remove the `else` from the code I provided above, or you may find yourself starting `worker1` and `worker2` many many times before 9:01 comes around.

Finally, it's definitely worth looking at the system scheduler, because as people have said, it's nicer to just let the OS handle that stuff. Windows makes scheduled tasks reasonably easy with native functionality (Task Scheduler under Administrative Tools). I don't know about *nix, but I'm sure it can't be that bad.

Comment: I was just coming to the same conclusions myself.  30 seconds is a rather odd and error-prone time to be sleeping.  I suspect he wanted something less than a minute to guard against the edge case of time-testing *just* before 9:00 and the loop (or other miscellaneous) overhead/system latency making his next time-test at *just* after 9:01.

Comment: @JohnY I assume that's the case as well. I think the right way to solve it is to just sleep for (close to) the right amount of time in the first place.

Comment: Regarding system schedulers:  Pretty much all Unix/Linux users are familiar with `crontab`, and if you are comfortable editing text files (which presumably almost all Unix/Linux users are), then nothing could be simpler.  In comparison the scheduler for Windows requires a whole lot of rigamarole (in the form of finding the damn scheduler in the first place, then doing lots of clicking, wading through the GUI, etc.).  I'm a Windows weenie myself and find the scheduler quite friendly, actually, but if you're on Stack Overflow, `crontab` should not be hard.

Answer (score 3):

How about this scenario:

```
while 1:                               # 09:59:59.97 

    if time.strftime("%H") == "09"     # 09:59:59.99  
    and time.strftime("%M") == "00":   # 10:00:00.01
```

You'd have to get lucky for this to happen, but who knows :-)

---

BTW `time.sleep(30)` means that you are likely to enter the loop twice at 09:00. I can't see how that's related to the issue we're discussing, though.

Comment: I don't think either of these is likely to be the OP's problem… but they're both real problems, and exactly why you shouldn't write code like this.

Comment: Yeah that's one possibility, but this has been happening quite regularly. Also starting the threads as I understand would take close to no time. So it should not be waiting inside the if.

Comment: The time inside the `if` body isn't relevant here. In fact, a slower body would make it _less_ likely to happen. If it takes, say, 30ms to fetch the time, format it as a string, and do a string comparison, then this should happen about 0.1% of the time, right? But if the body took 30s, so the whole loop only ran half as often, it would only be 0.05% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could rule out the issue proposed by @Kos like this:

```
while 1:

    now = time.localtime()
    hour = time.strftime("%H", now)
    min = time.strftime("%M", now)
    if hour == "09" and min == "00":
        print "Starting at: " + hour + ":" + min
        worker1.startThread()
        worker2.startThread()

    time.sleep(30)
```

This way you're not running strftime() on a moving target.